# Can I make a dependency property that's read-only?

Tags: .net, wpf, dependency-properties

I need this dependency property to be accessible for read operations only. Outside objects should not be able to assign values to it.

Comment: And your programming language is...

Comment: If c#, make the setter private. public object prop{ get; private set;}

Comment: @Mikael: That's not good enough, since dependency properties can be set (more directly) via SetValue of the DependencyObject.

Comment: Yes - you need to declare them with DepedencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly instead of Register.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, of course (think `IsMouseOver` for why read-only dependency properties **should** exist). [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754044.aspx#new) has a great article on the subject.

There are some issues implementing read-only dependency properties and in some situations they will not work. However, it is possible in some cases. For those cases, the following is a brief guide to implementing a readonly dependency property:

1. Use [`RegisterReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.registerreadonly.aspx) instead of `Register`.
2. Do not expose a public set method in your wrapped property.
3. The return value from `RegisterReadOnly` is of type [`DependencyPropertyKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencypropertykey.aspx) (instead of the usual `DependencyProperty`). Store but do not expose this value.

The linked article will give you the necessary details.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can.

MSDN has an entire section describing how to define and use [Read-Only Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754044.aspx).

The main issue is to call [DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.registerreadonly.aspx) instead of Register.  Also, if you create a property on the object to handle this, make sure to only implement a public getter in the property, and not a public setter.